# How can i remove/disable the auto disable permission feature?

Tags: permissions, auto, disable

Android has this feature now where it turns off app permissions if the app is not used for too long. There must be a way to turn this off or default the permission setting to off? It's ridiculous to have to go each app open the permissions and turn this off. It also seems that when apps update it turns this setting back on. This is just silly!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.